# How do I get the error event to fire in indexedDB.deleteDatabase?

Tags: indexeddb

[The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/deleteDatabase) says:

> If an error occurs while the database is being deleted, then an error
>   event is fired on the request object that is returned from this
>   method.

Q: How do I invoke an error so that I can see what's inside that event?
I tried to delete null, and undefined, and without using any parameters but I can't get the error callback to fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason an error would fire from deleteDatabase is if there was an internal error in the browser, e.g. the storage device holding the database was disconnected.

There's no way to trigger this case from script. Coincidentally, I noticed this while doing some spec work, filed a [spec issue](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/74), and added a clause to the [spec](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#deleting-a-database) to account for it: *"If this fails for any reason..."*

The details of the event can be found in the [steps for deleteDatabase](http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-deletedatabase):

> If *result* is an error set the error of request to *result* and dispatch
>   an event at *request*. The event must use the Event interface and set
>   the type attribute to "error".

Note that the follow-on details about bubbles/cancelable is an [open spec issue](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/86) itself.

Answer (score 1):

copy/pasted from original link you gave. and added onerror

```
var DBDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("toDoList");

DBDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("Error deleting database.");
};

DBDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  console.log("Database deleted successfully");

  console.log(request.result); // should be null
};

DBDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  console.error("error in deleting database");
//console.error = read coloring in console.  vs coloring with .log of console
  console.log(event);
}
```

purely guessing in below.

could there be some sort of wild "read/write/delete" permssion on location were indexeddb file is stored on the hard drive perhaps causing an "onerror"  or perhaps harddrive for example was a usb drive and was unplugged?

transaction still on going and hung up in a loop or something and not properly ending and in that never does a "oncomplete" event. to finish out the que.  and admin here pressing the "stinking delete button" but stopped from deleting the database. could easily see "non computer person" doing something, and trying delete something, while other stuff going on in other tabs and like.